# Ruby Gem LoadError

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, cocoapods

I am getting a ruby error when an app I am running tries to…

`require "xcodeproj/xcodeproj_ext"` (https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj)

The gem has been installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/xcodeproj-0.5.5.

`gem list xcodeproj` outputs the following...

`xcodeproj (0.5.5, 0.5.0, 0.4.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.1, 0.1.0)`

1. There is no xcodeproj_ext file or directory. What is it looking for?
2. How do I best go about debugging this?

UPDATE: The app that I am trying to running is using http://gembundler.com/

Comment: Sorry my answer was rubbish. What's the output of `gem list xcodeproj` on your machine?

Comment: No worries, I edited the answer to provide the output.

Comment: Oh so you're using bundler. The contents of Gemfile and Gemfile.lock would be useful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something was missing in the installed gem.

After removing the ~/.bundler folder and running `bundle install` again it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to require any other gems?  Try doing:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'xcodeproj'
```

Comment: With a simple demo script I can. Looking into this further it seems the script that eventually fails is in ~/.bundler. In ~/.bundler/ruby/1.8 there is also Xcodeproj installed.